# Can the length-limit of certain tags be extended?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In [How should we tag questions about specific plugins or themes?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-specific-plugins-or-themes) I was playing with the suggestion to prefix plugin and theme names with plugin and theme in their tags.

With that I ran over a length limit for tags. IIRC the plugin name was: *Wordpress Google XML Sitemap* resulting in [plugin-wordpress-google-xml-sitemap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-wordpress-google-xml-sitemap) which was too long.

Question is, can that limit be extended for certain "prefixed" tags like [plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) or [theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme)?

Comment: Seems like an argument for not using component tags. But they I know that's not the direction @JeffAtwood wants to go...

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - component tags generally worked very well. That's the only issue I ran over. Extending the limit looks like a solution to me but I do not know if it's possible. If it's not, well then, the plugin and theme tags are halfhearted.